# I have a code which stores classes on local storage for different elements but one of them is not stored? Any ideas why this is happening?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, local-storage

I have a code which every time i click the button it changes the background color of different elements by toggling classes and all these are stored in localStorage. But there is a class of one of my elements that isn't stored in localStorage. I don't know why because it is the same code as the rest. This shouldn't happen. The element that i am targeting to add class is the ".ps-stream" and the var that i store the localStorage is the "getFavStreamPost" Here is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if (typeof(localStorage) == 'undefined') {
    alert("Your browser does not support HTML5 localStorage. Try upgrading.")
  } else {
    if (localStorage.getItem("fav") != null && localStorage.getItem("toolbar") != null &&
      localStorage.getItem("makePost") != null && localStorage.getItem("typeOfPost") != null &&
      localStorage.getItem('streamFilter') != null && localStorage.getItem('streamPost') != null) {
      getFav = localStorage.fav;
      getFavTool = localStorage.toolbar;
      getFavMakePost = localStorage.makePost;
      getFavPostType = localStorage.typeOfPost;
      getFavStreamFilter = localStorage.streamFilter;
      getFavStreamPost = localStorage.streamPost;



      $(".widget--box").addClass('widget-darkmode');
      $(".ps-toolbar").addClass('toolbar-darkMode');
      $(".ps-postbox-content").addClass('postBox');
      $(".ps-postbox-tab").addClass('post-type');
      $(".ps-stream__filters").addClass('darkStreamFilter');
      $(".ps-stream").addClass('activityPost');

    }
  }



  button.on('click', function() {


    getFav = localStorage.fav;
    getFavTool = localStorage.toolbar;
    getFavMakePost = localStorage.makePost;
    getFavPostType = localStorage.typeOfPost;
    getFavStreamFilter = localStorage.streamFilter;
    getFavStreamPost = localStorage.streamPost;


    $(".widget--box").toggleClass('widget-darkmode');
    $(".ps-toolbar").toggleClass('toolbar-darkMode');
    $(".ps-postbox-content").toggleClass('postBox');
    $(".ps-postbox-tab").toggleClass('post-type');
    $(".ps-stream__filters").toggleClass('darkStreamFilter');
    $(".ps-stream").toggleClass('activityPost');



    if ($(".widget--box").hasClass('widget-darkmode') && $(".ps-toolbar").hasClass('toolbar-darkMode') &&
      $(".ps-postbox-content").hasClass('postBox') && $(".ps-postbox-tab").hasClass('post-type') &&
      $(".ps-stream__filters").hasClass('darkStreamFilter') && $(".ps-stream").hasClass('activityPost')) {
      localStorage.setItem('fav', 'widget-darkmode');
      localStorage.setItem('toolbar', 'toolbar-darkMode');
      localStorage.setItem('makePost', 'postBox');
      localStorage.setItem('typeOfPost', 'post-type');
      localStorage.setItem('streamFilter', 'darkStreamFilter');
      localStorage.setItem('streamPost', 'activityPost');


    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem('fav');
      localStorage.removeItem('toolbar');
      localStorage.removeItem('makePost');
      localStorage.removeItem('typeOfPost');
      localStorage.removeItem('streamFilter');
      localStorage.removeItem('streamPost');

    }

  });



}); // document ready
```

Any idea why the rest of the elements are stored and not this or any other additional element. Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: When you say it "isn't stored in local storage", how specifically have you validated this?  In your browser's debugging tools, view the local storage data.  Is the value there?  When you call `localStorage.setItem('streamPost', 'activityPost');`, nothing is added to local storage at all?  Don't just look at all of the code, debug the specific operation that is failing.  If that exact line of code does not store anything in local storage, something is very wrong.

Comment: I checked the localStorage after  i had clicked the button and the value was there. What is saw was key: streamPost, value: activityPost, then i refreshed the page and the value was still there but the color was gone from that element while the rest were there.

Comment: Then it's time to continue debugging.  You've confirmed that, contrary to the assumption made in the question, the value *is* indeed being stored.  So then where is the overall process failing?  When you load the page and "the color was gone", where are you setting the color?  Debug exactly that operation.  Your browser's debugging tools have a script debugger to help with this.  Place a breakpoint where you are trying to set the color.  Is that line of code reached when the page loads?  Do the variables have the values you expect?  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your code only sets data in localStorage when ALL of the elements have the appropriate class; it's all or nothing.

It would be better to store a single `darkMode` value in localStorage, and set all of the classes based on that.

Comment: I tried to store another value from another element but stil didn't work. I don't understand why this is happening because i checked the localStorage after i refreshed the page and the value was there but the element went back to its original color.

Comment: You code is only going to do something when ALL of the things that you are checking have an appropriate value, otherwise, it does nothing. So, one of your values is not what you expect, so nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I found the solution to my problem. The problem wasn't that the code couldn't save the value in local storage but another script was running after that script so it was talking the original values and not the values from the localStorage. So i had to make sure that my script runs last.